# Rx.NET Buffer emit all items on Cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, rx.net

I am using Rx.NET library and its method `Buffer` in the most simple manner like:

`observable.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10);`

It works great except the case when cancellation token is activated. When that occurs I would like `Buffer` to emit all events which it holds at that moment and not to wait until Timer ticks. Is that possible?

Example:
I have items 1, 2, 3 emitted in 2 seconds so limit 10 items is not reached and limit 5 seconds is not reached. Now cancellation is requested and I would like to get all buffered items to at least "see" them before ending request/process without waiting additional 3 seconds for timer.

Comment: A cancelation token means to cancel and not to "process a little more" and then cancel. I think you need to re-think the design. Can you please explain some more as to what you're trying to use a cancelation token to actually mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity I tend agree with you but it is simply impractical. Some times you need to react to cancellation at least by checking/logging what's is not going to be processed. Like when .net application is being shutdown you can register your callback on `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` cancellation token (which is the moment when I would like to flush the Buffer)

Comment: I think I initially read your question incorrectly. Is there any chance you could provide an example of what `observable` might be that demonstrates the issue you're facing and what the expected result should be? I think Oleg has nailed it, but I'd like to be able to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see the possible solution if I understand it correctly:

```
    public static IObservable<Unit> ToObservable(this CancellationToken ct) =>
        Observable.Create<Unit>(observer => ct.Register(() =>
            {
                observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                observer.OnCompleted();
            })
        );

    static void Main()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(6000);

        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
            .TakeUntil(cts.Token.ToObservable())
            .Buffer(10)
            .Subscribe(b=>
            {
                // ... processing
            });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The main idea is to finish Buffer's source sequence on cancellation request - it makes Buffer immediately release collected items and finish its work, and later on Subscribe you just check if the cancellation was requested and make an appropriate decision upon data arrived.

Comment: I don't think there is any need to use the `Using` and the `SingleAssignmentDisposable`. Just return the disposable from the `Register` call directly out of the `Create`. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Enigmativity You're completely right! (facepalm). Removing overengineering, thanks

Comment: Thank you. And while I'm at it, I don't think the `if(cts.IsCancellationRequested)` code is necessary. With it it seems to do what the OP wanted, if I'm reading the question correctly.